# Save a <canvas> as a file in a form

Tags: forms, canvas, file-upload

Using Canvas method toDataURL, I would like to be able to save the image on the server side (using Rails).

With toDataURL string, how to use it in a form that can be seen as a file attachment in a HTML form ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Solution using jQuery, Paperclip, datafy.rb
http://gist.github.com/397615

Answer (score 1):

Here is my solution:

- The problem: Compact uploaded images of any size before sending it to the server, which will save the image.
- Files involved: 2 ASP pages: one that will act client-side and another server-side.

The Presentation page:

```html
    <html>
    <!-- by arturmariojr@gmail.com - on december/2012 -->
    <script language='javaScript'>
    // Check for the various File API support.
        if (window.File && window.FileReader && window.FileList && window.Blob) {
          // Great success! All the File APIs are supported.
        } else {
            alert('Este Browser não suporte a API Files');
        }
        
        
        function Compactar(Elemento) {
            var file = document.getElementById(Elemento), 
                reader = new FileReader(),      // métodos assíncronos, por isso os eventos!
                form = document.getElementById('frmFotos');
            
            //alert(file.id);
            
            reader.readAsDataURL(file.files[0]);            // aqui a abertura do arquivo, que irá disparar a função acima
    
            reader.onloadend = function() {     // aqui um evento, que será disparado na primeira linha abaixo da função chamada 
                var image = new Image();
                image.src = reader.result;      // vai disparar o tratamento do evento abaixo
    
                image.onload = function() {
                    var maxWidth = 800,
                        maxHeight = 600,
                        width = image.width,
                        height = image.height;
                        
    
                    // calculate the width and height, constraining the proportions
                    if (width > height) {
                        if (width > maxWidth) {
                          //height *= max_width / width;
                          height = Math.round(height *= maxWidth / width);
                          width = maxWidth;
                        }
                    } else {
                        if (height > maxHeight) {
                          //width *= max_height / height;
                          width = Math.round(width *= maxHeight / height);
                          height = maxHeight;
                        }
                    }
    
                    var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
                    canvas.width = width;
                    canvas.height = height;
    
                    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
                    ctx.drawImage(image, 0, 0, maxWidth, maxHeight);
    
                    // The resized file ready for upload
                    var finalFile = canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg",0.8);     //a 80% de qualidade
                    
                    // aqui cria-se novo input comun!
                    /*var newinput = document.createElement("input");
                    newinput.type = 'text';
                    newinput.name = "edt" & Elemento;
                    newinput.value = finalFile; // put result from canvas into new hidden input
                    form.appendChild(newinput);*/
                    document.getElementById("edtArq_1").value = finalFile;
                    
                    var preview = document.getElementById('preview');
                    //alert(preview.id);
                    preview.appendChild(canvas); // do the actual resized preview
                        
                }
                
            }       
        }
    </script>
    
    <html>
   
    
    <form id="form" action="submit" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8" enctype="multipart/form-data">
   
    
    <!-- this will be left behind - we don't want to upload Mbytes of information -->
    
    <input type='file' name='Arq_1' id='Arq_1' size='50' onchange='Compactar("Arq_1");'>
    
    
    <form method="POST" id='frmFotos' action='SalvaArquivo.asp'>
    
    <!-- this could be a hidden element -->
    <input name='edtArq_1' id='edtArq_1'><br>
    
    <input type='submit' name ='cmdEnviar' id='cmdEnviar' value='Enviar' >
    </form>
    
    <!-- just for you see the new resized image - no upload too -->
    <div id="preview"></div>
    
    </html>
```

The page that will reveive the request from the first page and save the image:

```asp
    <html>
    <!-- by arturmariojr@gmail.com - on december/2012 -->
    <!-- this script could be avoided if I had put the img element in the page directly 
    . By the way, actualyy there's no necessity of showing nothing to user 
     -->
    <script language='JavaScript'>
        var newImg = document.createElement("img");
        newImg.src = '<%=request.form("edtArq_1")%>';
        document.body.appendChild(newImg);
    </script>
    
    <body>
    
    <input name='edtOriginal' value='<%=request.form("edtArq_1")%>'>
    
    <%
    ' the data is encoded, so, we will need to deencode it ...
    
    Function Base64Decode(ByVal base64String)
      'rfc1521
      '1999 Antonin Foller, Motobit Software, http://Motobit.cz
      Const Base64 = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/"
      Dim dataLength, sOut, groupBegin
      
      'remove white spaces, If any
      base64String = Replace(base64String, vbCrLf, "")
      base64String = Replace(base64String, vbTab, "")
      base64String = Replace(base64String, " ", "")
      
      'The source must consists from groups with Len of 4 chars
      dataLength = Len(base64String)
      If dataLength Mod 4 <> 0 Then
        Err.Raise 1, "Base64Decode", "Bad Base64 string."
        Exit Function
      End If
      
      ' Now decode each group:
      For groupBegin = 1 To dataLength Step 4
        Dim numDataBytes, CharCounter, thisChar, thisData, nGroup, pOut
        ' Each data group encodes up To 3 actual bytes.
        numDataBytes = 3
        nGroup = 0
    
        For CharCounter = 0 To 3
          ' Convert each character into 6 bits of data, And add it To
          ' an integer For temporary storage.  If a character is a '=', there
          ' is one fewer data byte.  (There can only be a maximum of 2 '=' In
          ' the whole string.)
    
          thisChar = Mid(base64String, groupBegin + CharCounter, 1)
    
          If thisChar = "=" Then
            numDataBytes = numDataBytes - 1
            thisData = 0
          Else
            thisData = InStr(1, Base64, thisChar, vbBinaryCompare) - 1
          End If
          If thisData = -1 Then
            Err.Raise 2, "Base64Decode", "Bad character In Base64 string."
            Exit Function
          End If
    
          nGroup = 64 * nGroup + thisData
        Next
        
        'Hex splits the long To 6 groups with 4 bits
        nGroup = Hex(nGroup)
        
        'Add leading zeros
        nGroup = String(6 - Len(nGroup), "0") & nGroup
        
        'Convert the 3 byte hex integer (6 chars) To 3 characters
        pOut = Chr(CByte("&H" & Mid(nGroup, 1, 2))) + _
          Chr(CByte("&H" & Mid(nGroup, 3, 2))) + _
          Chr(CByte("&H" & Mid(nGroup, 5, 2)))
        
        'add numDataBytes characters To out string
        sOut = sOut & Left(pOut, numDataBytes)
      Next
    
      Base64Decode = sOut
    End Function
    
    
    ' now, we will save the data (new image) using the old FileSystemObject !!!
    
    Set fso = Server.CreateObject ("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        Response.write "Não foi possível instanciar objeto fso!<br>" & Err.description
        response.end
    End if
    
    dim Caminho, objArq
    
    Caminho = Server.MapPath("./images")   'where I saved the new image
    response.write Caminho
    
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        Response.write "Não foi possível localizar caminho! " & Caminho & "<br>" & Err.description & "<br>"
    else
        Set oFile = fso.CreateTextFile(Caminho & "\Teste.jpg", true)
        oFile.Write Base64Decode(replace(request.form("edtArq_1"), "data:image/jpeg;base64,", "")) 'BinaryToString(request.from("edtArq_1"))
    
        If Err.Number <> 0 Then
            Response.write "Não foi possível localizar thum(s)!" & Caminho & "<br>" & Err.description & "<br>"
        end if
        
        oFile.close
    end if
    
    %>
    
    </body>
    </html>
```