# Pick up an image already drawed in canvas

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas, html5-canvas

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to send HTML <canvas> data to server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9478659/how-to-send-html-canvas-data-to-server)

I had made a form who can send a picture in base64 to php script. I have [**used this plugin**](http://www.xarg.org/project/jquery-webcam-plugin/) to capture image with flash and put it in the canvas (Useful for preview before post the form). But how can I get the actual picture data in canvas to send it via ajax ?

(Sorry for english !) :-)
Thank you

EDIT :

Solved !

I just pointed to the canvas

`canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');`

`pngBase64 = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");`

And in I POST my `pngBase64`

Comment: If you have solved your problem, and there is no other answers otherwise, please "Answer your own Question", then give it the Check, help keep Stack organized.

Comment: I cannot Answer my own question ! I have no more reputation :-(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
context = canvas.getContext("2d");
data = context.getImageData(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Canvas/Pixel_manipulation_with_canvas

Comment: Thank you @SpiderPig . So I get an array of data (Uint8ClampedArray). How can I transform it in base64 png or jpef for example ?